# How to go back to forms designer in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[image]

I am a complete newbie on visual basics. I got to this screen but don't know how to go back to designing my form. How can I go back to my form?.

Comment: vs is what I meant not vsc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemingly deleted the files `Form1.Designer.vb` and `Form1.resx` or did something else so that `Form1.vb` is no longer recognized as a `Form`, but as "normal" class .

So it is probably easiest to create a new `Form` by right clicking on the project inside `Solution Explorer` and then `Add > Form...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just right-click on the form in the Solutions Explorer and select "View Designer."  Or press Shift-F7.

Answer (score 0):

The `Form1` class seems to need to be the FIRST class in form1.vb. You can have other classes, but they have to be after it.
Then you can just double click on Form1.vb in the solution explorer window.

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to answer according to [answer]? This post looks more like some venting and ranting. Please [edit] or delete.